# Convert Bitmap to ByteArray and vice versa

Tags: java, android, bitmap, byte, bytebuffer

In my android application i want to convert image ,taken from camera, to byte array and convert back to  bitmap to view in a image view. I can do it easily through Bitmap.compress. But i want to do it without Bitmap.compress. The problem is that i am getting white lines (poor images every time(lines) )

```
                        Bitmap hello;    //image coming from camera
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(hello.getByteCount()); 
                        hello.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
                        byte[] bytes1 = buffer.array();
                        byte [] Bits = new byte[bytes1.length*4];
                        int i;
                   for(i=0;i<bytes1.length;i++)
                {
                    Bits[i*4] =
                        Bits[i*4+1] =
                        Bits[i*4+2] = (byte) ~bytes1[i]; //Invert the source bits
                    Bits[i*4+3] = -1;//0xff, that's the alpha.
                }

                Bitmap bmimage = Bitmap.createBitmap( 360,248, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                bmimage.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(Bits));
                imageView11.setImageBitmap(bmimage);
```

Comment: And is there any significant reason why not to use build-in method `compress` and use your hardcoded approach?

Comment: and now, what is the reason to avoid Bitmap.compress ?

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap to byte array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();
```

or

```
int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); 
byte[] array = buffer.array();
```

byte array to Bitmap:

```
 InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
  BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
```

Comment: When I do byte array to Bitmap: which you show I have a nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    ///useing following code 
    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: You should read question more carefully. He said that he doesn't want to use compress method.