# bebop Bytebuffer to bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bytebuffer

I'm trying to create a bitmap using the Bytebuffer in Bebop drone.
Here it is how I tried.

```
    ByteBuffer b;                        
    b.put(frame.getByteData(), 0, frame.getDataSize());
    bytesToBitmap(b);
    imageSave(myImage);
```

---

```
    public Bitmap bytesToBitmap(ByteBuffer b){

    myImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    a = new byte[b.remaining()];
    b.get(a);
    IntBuffer intBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(a).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
    int[] array = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
    intBuf.get(array);
    myImage.setPixels(array, 0, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(myImage);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(myImage, 0,0, null);
    Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight());
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(myImage, src, dest, null);
    canvas.save();
    return myImage;
    }
```

finally, saved bitmap is as follows:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UysX0.jpg)

Did I do wrong?

What is wrong?
Please answer, thank you.

Comment: is there any issue? post that.

Comment: [Convert Bitmap to ByteArray and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702481/convert-bitmap-to-bytearray-and-vice-versa) Related Question, have you tried this?

Comment: @DevendraSingh, the issue is the same as the attached picture.

Comment: @Underbalanced, I try that. And I show you the result bitmap.

Comment: @Underbalanced, your link is inverse. I tried them, it is not working.

Comment: @kimms the link is both ways actually ways to and from.